# how can i get the version of msi

Tags: windows-installer, version

how can i get the version of my msi ? 
[image: Version]

i have tried with this:

```
 private void barButtonItem_Version_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Version" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
        }
```

and i have tried also:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Version: " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
```

and this code:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
            string version = fvi.FileVersion;

            MessageBox.Show("Version: " + version);
```

and this code:

```
  string productVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;

            MessageBox.Show("Version: " + productVersion);
```

and this:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Version: " + Application.ProductVersion);
```

but all of them return 1.0.0.0 as you can see on image my version is 1.0.0

thanks you in advance

Comment: _What_ version? Assembly, file or product? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1605873/560648

Comment: i guess version of product

Comment: You forgot to follow the link I gave you

Answer (score 1):

This version is stored in the property ProductVersion from Property table in your MSI. You can query that table easily to get the property value: [How to read MSI properties in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950420/how-to-read-msi-properties-in-c-sharp)